# Why does axios keep sending requests?

Tags: javascript, axios, nodemon

This is my code:

```
var axios = require("axios").default;
var btoa = require("btoa")

var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://qrcode3.p.rapidapi.com/qrcode/text',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'qrcode3.p.rapidapi.com',
    'x-rapidapi-key': '*****'
  },
  data: {
    data: 'https://linqr.app',
    image: {uri: 'icon://appstore', modules: true},
    style: {
      module: {color: 'black', shape: 'default'},
      inner_eye: {shape: 'default'},
      outer_eye: {shape: 'default'},
      background: {}
    },
    size: {width: 200, quiet_zone: 4, error_correction: 'M'},
    output: {filename: 'qrcode', format: 'png'}
  }
};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
    console.log(btoa(response.data));
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

I run the file with nodemon and it keeps sending requests over and over again... why does it not send the request only once?

Comment: Is that literally all that's in the file? Exactly what command are you using to run it?

Comment: It's fine. It sends only one request and you get the whole response.